# isset($_POST) not working but isset($_GET) working... why?

Tags: php, html

When i write - `if(isset($_POST['submit']))` ,it always evaluates to false.. whereas if i simply change `$_POST` to `$_GET`, it works properly.

My HTML code-

```
<html>
    <body>
        <form action="welcome.php" action="post">
            <input type="text" name="username"> <br>
            <input type="submit" name="send">Click me </input>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

My PHP code-

```
<?php
$name="default";
if(isset($_POST['send'])){
    $name = $_POST['username'];
}
echo $name;
?>
```

**The output i get is "default" and not what i type in input field in the html** form.. Can you tell why? Thanks in advance.

Comment: The right attribute is `method`.

Comment: This is a typo question; being off-topic.

Comment: *"but isset($_GET) working… why?"* - Because; the method's wrong (there is none) and when it fails, it defaults to GET; would you like this as answer? because that's what's really going on here.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Always when I give a good answer... = P

Comment: @JazZ Indeed. I just thought I'd add another answer up here ;-) as to why exactly it failed and why it worked for GET.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Great ! Added that to my answer.

Comment: @JazZ I added a community wiki answer; I didn't want rep from this.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Ok, just saw that. Nice.

Comment: In case this _wasn't_ just a typo, here's a nice reference for HTML form attributes: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form#Attributes

Comment: I really didn't think it'd be a typo.. god i feel stupid! Thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The right attribute to set the method of the request is `method` :

```
<html>
    <body>
        <form action="welcome.php" method="post">
            <input type="text" name="username"> <br>
            <input type="submit" name="send" />
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: my god! can't believe i spent 2 hours trying to fix this! xD Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I'll just add my comment as a community wiki answer; I don't want rep from this.

> *"but isset($_GET) working… why?"*

Because; the method's wrong (there is none) and when it fails, it (form) **defaults** to a GET method.

That's what's really going on here.